# Backbone: invoke containing view's function on ADD event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**I have** a View which contains collection.

**I want:** handle collection add event inside a View.

**Question:** *How to handle `add` event inside View?*

**Code:**

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  collection: null,
  subViews: [],

  setCollection: function(collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
  },

  // HOW TO CALL THIS FUNCTION ON COLLECTION ADD EVENT?
  handleCollectionAdd: function(model) {
    X = ....
    subViews[X] = new SubView(model); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to add event on collection in initialize function of View using

```
initialize: function(){
   this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', handleCollectionAdd);
}
```